# Filter max values by row and columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe.

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
    Beam  Pos Comb   As  
0    B1    1    1    3          
1    B1    1    1    2          
2    B1    2    1    5          
3    B1    2    1    8          
4    B1    1    2    10         
5    B1    1    2    1         
6    B1    2    2    3          
7    B1    2    2    2
8    B2    1    1    1          
9    B2    1    1    2          
10   B2    2    1    5          
11   B2    2    1    6          
12   B2    1    2    8         
13   B2    1    2    1         
14   B2    2    2    3          
15   B2    2    2    2
```

I need to get the max value per beam and position searching in diferent combinations.

```
    Beam  Pos Comb   As
0    B1    1    2    10         
1    B1    2    1    8         
2    B2    1    2    8          
3    B2    2    1    6
```

I can't figured out how can I compare the "As" values for Beam, position and combination.

Perhaps grouping the beam, the positions and then get the max value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
groups = df.groupby(by=['Beam', "Pos"])
idx = []
for group in groups:
    idx += [group[1].As.argmax()]
```

than show
    `df.iloc[idx]`

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I need the max value per beam and position. But every beam has diferent combination with diferent "As" values per position.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, this can be another option. I´ll try it.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thanks Alexander. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the `groupby` method on the multi level index:

```
d = df.groupby(by= [ "Beam",  "Pos", "Comb"])
g=d.agg({"As":"max"})
g.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

the first line groups together the items that have the same `(Beam,Pos,Comb)` index,
the second line select the max `As` on each group and the `reset_index` undo the groups in the dataframe

Comment: Thanks JMat. Yes I know it. But every beam has a position and diferent combinations. I need to get the max value per beam and position searching in diferent combinations.

Comment: @Eduardo, sorry, I didn't understand the question, I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks!, I think this is what I need. "g" is the result dataframe?

Comment: yes, but you can put everything in one line of course: `df = df.groupby(by= [ "Beam",  "Pos", "Comb"]).agg({"As":"max"}).reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: @Eduardo ok I edited the answer, you have to do the `.reset_index` on a different line or do `g=d.agg({"As":"max"}).reset_index(inplace=False)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the same result as the A.Kot method. I need one last step to filter the combination.

Comment: I changed the first line with `d = df.groupby(by= [ "Beam",  "Pos"])` and works great.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the native pandas functions instead of recreating the wheel to make this extremely simple and easy to remember:

```
df.groupby(['Beam', 'Pos', 'Comb']).max()
```

Comment: This method shows all combination. I need one last step that choice the combination with the max value.

Comment: It shows the maximum value for each combination. What else are you looking for?

Comment: I solved the problem with the Alexander Zhukov answer. Thank you @A.Kot